# How can I correctly print Arabic through Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, imagemagick, arabic, rmagick

I'm trying to generate images through RMagick that contain Arabic text that has been parsed from an excel spreadsheet. Arabic letters change shape depending on their neighbors and this seems to happen in excel for displaying purposes only. The letters are not stored in their modified form, so they print out incorrectly. Does anyone know of a library that addresses this? TIA

Comment: As always, it helps if you include sample code and data that demonstrates the problem. Are you using Ruby's UNICODE support?

Comment: Well I can't seem to past unicode here, but all that's needed to recreate the issue is to try and print out an arabic word to console. So the script contains `puts "#{arabic_word}"`, what is printed to the console is different from what is typed into the text editor. Unicode support isn't the problem; it's Arabic specific.

Comment: You should be able to paste Unicode characters here: ببب. Are you sure your environment is set up correctly?

Comment: Yea, I didn't bother trying, but here it is: ببب

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ruby are you using? Also, is ImageMagick supposed to render Arabic text correctly in the first place? If not, you might want to use Prawn or something to generate a PDF file...

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.8. It's not an ImageMagick issue. The text renders fine, but like I said, I get the wrong characters. I actually found a gem for Prawn that is supposed to fix the strings for Arabic letters and it gets them a lot closer, but it's not perfect. Ideally, I just need a library or function that will scan through the string in Arabic and replace each character with the appropriate one.

Comment: "I just need a library or function that will scan through the string in Arabic" -- no, in fact that's *not* what you need. What you need is a renderer that properly implements Unicode Arabic shaping behavior, so that you don't have to do this at the app level.

Comment: BTW, if you can use Ruby 1.9 for this, do. It handles Unicode text much better than 1.8.

Comment: You might find http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18872 helpful. Looks like IM can't do this itself, and people are recommending Pango to preprocess the Arabic.

Comment: That may not be what I need, but it would certainly get me there. Is there any reason for me to think that 1.9 will do this natively?

Comment: Probably not: your issue is with ImageMagick, not with Ruby. See the link I posted in my previous response. However, there may be some Arabic text-handling routines in Ruby 1.9 that I'm not aware of. What Ruby 1.9 *will* do, however, is handle the Arabic text better for Ruby string operations.

Comment: Thanks, Marnen, I took a look at that thread but couldn't find anything directly applicable. What about the case of someone wanting to print Arabic text to the console?

Comment: In that case, the system text-rendering routines would normally be expected to take care of the shaping. What do you mean that you couldn't find anything directly applicable in that thread? It discusses your exact problem.

Comment: The thread was originally created to address the ability to render from right to left, which is not exactly my problem. There are a few people who touch on third party programs and some talk of using Pango within IM. I don't know if I could leverage Pango myself for this; I have some limited Pango experience, but it doesn't jump out at me.

Comment: Not just RTL You'll notice that one example has IM doing RTL, but without shaping. Looks like IM can't do the shaping itself, so try Pango or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **reshape** Arabic text in **Ruby** for ImageMagick/RMagick to render it correctly.

This is already solved for **Java**([Better-Arabic-Reshaper](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper)) and **Python**([arabic_reshaper](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper)). Do the same task in Ruby text before passing it to ImageMagick. [linux CLI: how to render Arabic text into bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536375/linux-cli-how-to-render-arabic-text-into-bitmap/25721286#25721286)