# linux CLI: how to render Arabic text into bitmap

Tags: ruby, linux, imagemagick, arabic, rmagick

I would like to draw Arabic text into bitmap (bmp or png) with command line interface.

I have tried imagemagick and RMagick, but I have problem with RTL language issue. all my rendering are left to right. And google is not helping.

require:

```
./render "لوحة المفاتيح" out.png
```

would give a bitmap:

لوحة المفاتيح

Anyone can give me some successful results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Anyone can give me some successful results?

I can. I use `convert` from ImageMagick:

```
echo لوحة المفاتيح > text.txt && \
convert -size 300x200 \
        -background white \
        -fill black \
        -font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf \
        -pointsize 24 \
        -gravity Center \
        label:@text.txt \
        text.png
```

This is the result:

[image: Text to image result]

Some notes:

1. You need to use a font which defines the used characters (in your case an arabic font)
2. Always use a temporary file with the text inside instead of provide the text directly from the command line: it would lead to weird results

**UPDATE** I didn't notice the RTL part of the question; I think I got better results using pango ([reference](http://tillawy.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/render-rtl-arabic-text-image-pango-view-howto/)):

```
# On Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev
echo -n لوحة المفاتيح > text.txt
pango-view text.txt --no-display --output text.png
```

Result:

[image: Text to image result using pango]

Comment: thanks, but this is incorrect, Arabic is Right to Left, correct should be:  "لوحة المفاتيح", but your one is   "حيتافملا ةحول"

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice the RTL part of your question :-/

Comment: It's ok, I am not an Arabic language speaker, and don't recognize any characters. very confusing indeed.

Comment: I noticed that setting dpi (using `--dpi=500` for example) affects the font size, but I didn't investigate further :)

Answer (score 4):

For Arabic typography, you might want to use **Inkscape 0.9** as follows (Window7 cmd):

```
inkscape "ar.svg" --export-png="C:\Users\Path\TO\output\arabicthabit.png" --export-dpi="900,900" --export-background="rgb(100%,100%,100%)"
```

Where **ar.svg** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="400"
   height="100"
   version="1.1">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-size:30px;font-style:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:'Droid Arabic Naskh';font-weight:bold;"
       x="10" y="90"
         ><tspan>لغةٌ عربيّةٌ</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

[image]

You can replace the `font-family:'Droid Arabic Naskh'` by any font in your system.
Also you can change the output format as stated in the man pages of Inkscape. Moreover, you can start in Inkscape GUI and save the SVG and change what you want in the SVG XML in any scripting language.

**Inkscape 0.48** returned buggy Arabic typography.

As for **ImageMagick 6.8.9-7**, I used Python +Wand(Python Lib)+arabic_reshaper(Python Lib)+bidi.algorithme(Python Lib) to generate correct Arabic typography in images:

```
from wand.image import Image as wImage
from wand.display import display as wdiplay
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'لغةٌ عربيّة')
artext = get_display(reshaped_text)

fonts = ['C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\Thabit.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\Thabit-Bold-Oblique.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\Thabit-Bold.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\Thabit-Oblique.ttf',
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\majalla.ttf',         
         'C:\\Users\\PATH\\TO\\FONT\\Thabit-0.02\\majallab.ttf',

         ]
draw = Drawing()
img =  wImage(width=1200,height=(len(fonts)+2)*60,background=Color('#ffffff')) 
#draw.fill_color(Color('#000000'))
draw.text_alignment = 'right';
draw.text_antialias = True
draw.text_encoding = 'utf-8'
#draw.text_interline_spacing = 1
#draw.text_interword_spacing = 15.0
draw.text_kerning = 0.0
for i in range(len(fonts)):
    font =  fonts[i]
    draw.font = font
    draw.font_size = 40
    draw.text(img.width / 2, 40+(i*60),artext)
    print draw.get_font_metrics(img,artext)
    draw(img)
draw.text(img.width / 2, 40+((i+1)*60),u'ناصر test')
draw(img)
img.save(filename='C:\\PATH\\OUTPUT\\arabictest.png'.format(r))
wdiplay(img)
```

[image: Arabic typography in images]